# Change of random variables and check by plot

Tags: monte-carlo, probability, calculus

**Question**

As a test, I transform a uniform distribution over the unit square.

But when I check the transformed distribution with Monte Carlo, it is wrong.

What went wrong?

Thanks.

---

**Problem**

- Random variables $\vec{X} = (X_1, X_2)$ follows the uniform distribution over the unit square.

  In other words, $X_{1} \sim U[0, 1]$ and $X_{2} \sim U[0, 1]$. $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ are independent.

  The probability density is: $\rho_{X}(x_{1}, x_{2}) = 1$
- The transformation $f(\vec{x}) = \vec{y}$ is:

$$y_{1} = \text{sigmoid}(x_{1} + x_{2}) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-(x_1 + x_2)}}$$
$$y_{2} = \text{sigmoid}(x_{1} - x_{2}) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-(x_1 - x_2)}}$$

Find probability density $\rho_{Y}( y_{1}, y_{2})$

---

**Attempt**

The inverse transform $f^{-1}(\vec{y}) = \vec{x}$ is:

$$x_{1} = (a_{1} + a_{2}) / 2$$
$$x_{2} = (a_{1} - a_{2}) / 2$$

where

$$a_{1} = x_{1} + x_{2} = -\log\left(\frac{1}{y_1} - 1\right) = \log(y_{1}) - \log(1 - y_{1})$$

$$a_{2} = x_{1} - x_{2} = -\log\left(\frac{1}{y_2} - 1\right) = \log(y_{2}) - \log(1 - y_{2})$$

The partial derivatives of $a_{1}$ and $a_{2}$ are:

$$\frac{\partial a_{1}}{\partial y_{1}} = \frac{1}{y_{1}} - \frac{1}{1 - y_{1}} \cdot -1 = \frac{1}{y_{1}(1 - y_{1})} $$

$$\frac{\partial a_{2}}{\partial y_{2}} = \frac{1}{y_{2}(1 - y_{2})} $$

The Jacobian of the inverse transform $f^{-1}(\vec{y}) = \vec{x}$ is:

$$J =\begin{bmatrix} 
\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial y_1} & \frac{\partial x_1}{\partial y_2} \\
\frac{\partial x_2}{\partial y_1} & \frac{\partial x_2}{\partial y_2} \\
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
\frac{\ 1}{\ 2 y_{1} (1 - y_{1})} & \frac{1}{\ 2 y_{2} (1 - y_{2})} \\
\frac{1}{ 2 y_{1} (1 - y_{1})} & -\frac{1}{\ 2 y_{2} (1 - y_{2})} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The determinant of the Jacobian is:

$$\det(J) = -\frac{1}{2y_{1}(1 - y_{1})y_{2}(1 - y_{2})}$$

The probability density of the transformed distribution is:

$$\rho_{Y}(\vec{y}) = \rho_{X}(f^{-1}(\vec{y})) \lvert \det(J(\vec{y})) \rvert = \frac{1}{2y_{1}(1 - y_{1})y_{2}(1 - y_{2})} $$

---

**Check**

- Draw samples of $\vec{X}$
- Transform samples of $\vec{X}$ to samples of $\vec{Y}$
- Compute a weighted 2 dimensional histogram of the samples of $\vec{Y}$
- The weights are $1 / \rho_{Y}(\vec{y})$
- I expect the weighted histogram would reflect an uniform distribution

Result of the program

[image: Result of the program]

Contrary to my expectation, the result is not an uniform distribution. What went wrong?

Program:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def sample_x(n_trials, eps=1e-5):
    """Draw samples from X"""
    return np.random.uniform(eps, 1 - eps, size=(2, n_trials))


def transform_samples(x):
    """Transform samples of X to samples of Y"""
    n_trials = x.shape[1]
    y = np.empty((2, n_trials))
    y[0] = x[0] + x[1]
    y[1] = x[0] - x[1]
    y = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-y))
    return y


def cal_det_jac(y):
    """Calculate absolute determinant of the
    Jacobian of the inverse transform"""
    a = y[0] * (y[0] - 1)
    b = y[1] * (y[1] - 1)
    return 1 / (2 * a * b)


def make_histogram(grid_size, ndim):
    shape = (grid_size,) * ndim
    return np.zeros(shape)


def update_historgram(histogram, sample, weight):
    """Update the histogram.
    Assumes the sample is within the unit square"""
    grid_size = histogram.shape[0]
    index = (sample * grid_size).astype(int)
    histogram[index] += weight


def main():
    # Draw samples from Y
    n_trials = 100000
    x = sample_x(n_trials)
    y = transform_samples(x)

    # Calculate weights of histogram
    w = 1 / cal_det_jac(y)

    # Calculate 2D histogram
    grid_size = 100
    hist = make_histogram(grid_size, 2)
    for i in range(n_trials):
        update_historgram(hist, y[:, i], w[i])

    # Plot
    plt.pcolor(hist)
    plt.show()
    plt.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I fix it. The line in the `update_histogram(...)` function should be:

`histogram[index[0], index[1]] += weight`

instead of

`histogram[index] += weight`

Result:

[image]